# MySQL: Insert rows using a column from another new table

Tags: mysql, insert

I've been fighting to get the SQL right on this insert statement.. here's what I'm trying to do:

I have new empty table that has a 1-to-1 relationship with another table. Since all the other columns have default values I only want to insert the primary key column as new rows from the old table. Table names are `dealer` and `dealer_nav` and the fields are `id` and `dealer_id` respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: the other values can be blank.. defaults are already set in the structure of the table.. all other fields n the new table are boolean with FALSE (0) as default

Comment: what have you tried, what exactly is the problem and what error-message are you facing? you're describing what you wan't to do (thanks for that, most peaople miss that part), but we don't know whats the problem with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT INTO dealer_nav(dealer_id) SELECT id FROM dealer` (or vice versa, I'm not sure which of 2 tables is new and which is old)